# select posts with any tags except for certain tag

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose I have Post, that can have 0-n Tags.  I'm trying to write a query to return posts that have any tags at all, except for a certain tag.

```
posts
=====
id
-----
1
2
3
4

tags
====
id | name
----------
1  | apples
2  | bananas
3  | carrots

taggings
========
post_id | tag_id
----------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
3       | 1
3       | 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3efab5/4

I want to select all posts that have zero or more tags, except those that have the "carrots" tag.

Something like this

```
select * 
from posts
left join taggings on taggings.post_id = posts.id
left join tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
where tags.name is null or tags.name not in ('carrots')
```

Except I expect it to return 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not exits`;

```
select * 
from posts
where not exists (select 1
                  from taggings join
                       tags
                       on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
                  where taggings.post_id = posts.id and tags.name in ('carrots')
                 );
```